# OpenSSL 1.1.1d gives the error on DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0 in bio.h

Tags: openssl, python, c++

I had used the earlier version OpenSSL 1.0.2s which ran perfectly as there was no such usage of DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0 in bio.h while the new version 1.1.1d encloses the functions like BIO_get_port using DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0 as below:

DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(int BIO_get_port(const char *str, unsigned short *port_ptr))

So we are ending up in error while compiling the c++ code using this new version. The error is as below:

In file included 
from C:/Users/sys_platformtools/Documents/PFT/external-components/include/openssl/openssl/pem.h:14:0,
from C:/Users/sys_platformtools/Documents/PFT/sdk/src/Core/CoreSSL/include/KeyHashHelper.h:30,
from C:\Users\sys_platformtools\Documents\PFT\sdk\src\Core\CoreSSL\src\KeyHashHelper.cpp:27:
C:/Users/sys_platformtools/Documents/PFT/external-components/include/openssl/openssl/bio.h:686:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0'
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(int BIO_get_port(const char *str, unsigned short *port_ptr))

Hence, can someone please put some light on the usage of DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0 and the steps to debug on this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Voting to migrate: This is a programming question, not a security question.

Comment: You need to fix your code. `BIO_get_port` is no longer there. It was essentially doing `getservbyname` internally so you need to fix your code to use `getservbyname` directly instead.

Comment: "Access to deprecated functions/macros has been removed by default. To enable access you must do two things. 1) Build OpenSSL with deprecation support (pass "enable-deprecated" as an argument to config) 2) Applications must define "OPENSSL_USE_DEPRECATED" before including OpenSSL header files"

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes#Major_Changes_so_far

Comment: @Swashbuckler Aside from this question being off-topic, the advice of "Here's how to enable deprecated functions", especially for any cryptographic tasks, is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: How do we call getservbyname method using openssl